# Get list of files in a specific Netsuite folder

Tags: c#, netsuite

I'm trying to retrieve a list of files in a specific folder in the file cabinet.  When I execute the search, I'm given all files in the specified folder and all folders underneath that folder.  I've tried with `FileSearchBasic` and `FileSearchAdvanced`, both give me the same results.

Is there a way to get only files in the specified folder id?

```
var search = new FileSearchBasic
{
    folder = new SearchMultiSelectField
    {
        @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        @operatorSpecified = true,
        searchValue = new[] { new RecordRef
        {
            internalId = "1234"
        }}
    }
};

var result = ns.search(search);
if (result.status.isSuccess)
{
    foreach (var record in result.recordList)
    {
        if (record is File file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file.folder.internalId} - {file.name}");
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in the following list where folder 1236 is a sub folder of folder 1234

```
1234 - lodash.js
1234 - dt.timer.js
1234 - dt.search.js
1234 - dt.customer.js
1234 - dt.safeExecute.js
1236 - processRawLocationData.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get only the files in the specified folder by performing a `FolderSearchAdvanced()` and using a file join rather than a `FileSearchAdvanced()`.  It sort of makes sense since you have to do it this way in SuiteScript as well.

Still open to alternative methods.

```
var search = new FolderSearchAdvanced()
{
    criteria = new FolderSearch()
    {
        basic = new FolderSearchBasic()
        {
            internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField()
            {
                @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                searchValue = new[] { searchValue },
                operatorSpecified = true
            },
        }
    },
    columns = new FolderSearchRow
    {
        basic = new FolderSearchRowBasic()
        {
            internalId = new[] { new SearchColumnSelectField() },
            name = new [] { new SearchColumnStringField() }
        },
        fileJoin = new FileSearchRowBasic()
        {
            internalId = new[] { new SearchColumnSelectField() },
            name = new[] { new SearchColumnStringField() },
            modified = new[] { new SearchColumnDateField() },
            documentSize = new[] { new SearchColumnLongField() }
        }
    }
};

var results = ns.search(search);
if (results.status.isSuccess)
{
    foreach (var result in results.searchRowList)
    {
        if (result is FolderSearchRow row)
        {
            var fileId = row.fileJoin.internalId[0].searchValue.internalId;
            var fileName = row.fileJoin.name[0].searchValue;

            Console.WriteLine($"{fileId} - {fileName}");
        }
    }
}
```